# GraphQL with SpringBoot and Gradle not working

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I tried creating a sample application to implement GraphQL with Spring Boot and Gradle, but somehow it's not working for me. Getting below error:

[GraphQL_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6JG9.jpg)

Code is at at location:
https://github.com/devilking01/GraphQlDemo

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [`graphql-spring-boot-starter`](https://github.com/merapar/graphql-spring-boot-starter) docs default request mapping is on `/v1/graphql` not `/graphql`.

You can also override default in properties file:

```
com.merapar.graphql:
   path: "/graphql"
```

Comment: not sure, how will i do this. Could you please suggest

Comment: No that url doesn't work. Just to clarify, as in the screenshot, I am using different url i.e. /graphiql, which internally calls /graphql. I tried same application with Maven and it worked fine. But I need to implement this with gradle.

Comment: both /v1/graphql and /graphql are not working when I build project using Gradle. But with maven build /graphql url is working. Please help.

Comment: I've checked the application start logs and found that following mapping is missing in gradle project "[ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet simpleGraphQLHttpServlet mapped to [/graphql/*]". Is there any help around this??